# GitKraken won't update on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gitkraken

My GitKraken does not complete the upgrade process, it gets caught on the download screen.

- A few weeks ago it worked normally
- Ubuntu Mate 18.04

[image]

Comment: Is it any permission related problem?

Comment: Did you solve this? the same is happening to me on Debian 9

Comment: It has not been solved yet, the problem persists to this day.

Comment: @MatíasCánepa I keep using it, but it is not the latest version because of this problem.Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've istalled 4.2.2 and I see a button to upgrade to 5.0.4. Choose .deb and then I see the same as your screenshot.

Comment: I think it's some permission problem, but it started to happen suddenly.

Comment: For personal reasons, I migrated from Ubuntu to Windows 10. These problems no longer persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just download te install package from the oficial page web(https://www.gitkraken.com/download) and install, thats work for me, sorry for my english

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem, so I installed GitKraken using command line:

- Open the Ubuntu's **Terminal** app
- Download the Linux `deb`package from https://www.gitkraken.com/download:

  - `wget https://release.gitkraken.com/linux/gitkraken-amd64.deb`
- Install the deb package:

  - `sudo dpkg -i ./gitkraken-amd64.deb`

Better yet, put all that into a `gitkraken_update.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
echo " Installing GitKraken..."
cd ${HOME}/Downloads
wget https://release.gitkraken.com/linux/gitkraken-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i ./gitkraken-amd64.deb
echo " Done."
```